# Python Pywinauto module : How to make a selection from Windows 10 taskbar right-click options

Tags: pywinauto

I'm able to right click on the taskbar using the following code
from pywinauto import taskbar

#taskbar.TaskBar.print_control_identifiers()
taskbar.TaskBar.Button.right_click()

But when I tried to select a menu item such as Cascade windows, I've been unsuccessful

cascade = taskbar.TaskBar.Button.right_click().child_window(title="Cascade windows", control_type="MenuItem").wrapper_object()
cascade.click_input()

I was wondering if you can help me with giving me an idea as to how can I select other right-click options from Windows 10 taskbar like:

Cascade windows
Show windows stacked
Show windows side by side

using pywinauto.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i faced a problem kinda similar to yours and that was my solution:

---

```py
import pywinauto 

from pywinauto import taskbar

explorer = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(path = "explorer.exe")
pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper(pywinauto.taskbar.TaskBarHandle()).right_click()
print(explorer.PopupMenu.menu().get_menu_path("Show windows side by side")[0].click_input())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).